# Docker /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper using 2.7GB

Tags: java, docker, device-mapper

I am a developer in [codiva online ide](https://www.codiva.io/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=devicemapper&utm_campaign=sof-questions). Every time the user runs a java program, we start a new container. We use devicemapper storage driver because that is the only way we were able to set an upper limit on the container size.

After a few months of usage, we are seeing that the disk usage is increasing, and /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper takes around 2.7GB.

I have deleted all the docker containers that are not running, and any dangling volumes, unfortunately, the disk usage for /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper still show up as 2.7GB.

What is the best way to reclaim this space? We don't need any persistent storage, we are okay with deleting all the data, because any data that needs to be stored, we mount the host directory directly, and those files are managed outside of docker.

```
sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

There are no running or even stopped containers.
The docker info results here.

```
$ sudo docker info
Containers: 1
Images: 14
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-143417-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 107.4 GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 2.591 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 1.469 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 2.531 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 1.469 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.77 (2012-10-15)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-76-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 992.5 MiB
Name: ip-172-31-26-50
ID: NIQ5:2NDW:SB77:ZNZU:UO6G:EYLB:JIW7:SQLL:QLWY:LNRM:SU6P:ZS7X
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

There are no dangling or orphaned volumes.

```
sudo docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
```

The only image is java:8

```
sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
java                8                   289bdffc37d7        3 weeks ago         669.2 MB
```

I had already followed the instructions is https://lebkowski.name/docker-volumes/ and still it is using unnecessary extra space.

Edit1: 
I have added the results of `docker images -a`. This shows a large number unnamed images. The size seems suspicious, as the sum of all these images goes upto 4.5GB, but my entire `/var/lib/docker` is only around 2.7GB.

```
$ sudo docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
java                8                   289bdffc37d7        3 weeks ago         669.2 MB
<none>              <none>              5d7cc49c4372        3 weeks ago         668.8 MB
<none>              <none>              9e756f3b105a        3 weeks ago         310.9 MB
<none>              <none>              7615ebf33bb7        3 weeks ago         310.9 MB
<none>              <none>              ac079291ad51        3 weeks ago         310.9 MB
<none>              <none>              cd02ed4609aa        3 weeks ago         310.9 MB
<none>              <none>              07bbd1c2007f        3 weeks ago         310.9 MB
<none>              <none>              6331ed9a346a        3 weeks ago         310.9 MB
<none>              <none>              b647ad8e0a08        3 weeks ago         310.9 MB
<none>              <none>              f23012d4423e        3 weeks ago         310.9 MB
<none>              <none>              0d3e866c82f3        3 weeks ago         301 MB
<none>              <none>              c28cbef85c39        3 weeks ago         169.7 MB
<none>              <none>              3f0d3d140ce1        3 weeks ago         125.1 MB
<none>              <none>              17bd2058e0c6        3 weeks ago         125.1 MB
```

On trying to one of them I get the error.
    $ sudo docker rmi 5d7cc49c4372
    Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 5d7cc49c4372 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
    Error: failed to remove images: [5d7cc49c4372]

On reading about it, is seems that the only required image java:8 depends on these child images.

```
$ sudo docker history 289bdffc37d7
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
289bdffc37d7        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates   418.2 kB            
5d7cc49c4372        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -x  && apt-get update  && apt-   357.9 MB            
7615ebf33bb7        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VE   0 B                 
9e756f3b105a        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u9   0 B                 
ac079291ad51        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV JAVA_VERSION=8u91         0 B                 
07bbd1c2007f        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/   0 B                 
cd02ed4609aa        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c {   echo '#!/bin/sh';   echo 'set    87 B                
b647ad8e0a08        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV LANG=C.UTF-8              0 B                 
6331ed9a346a        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.   61 B                
f23012d4423e        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    9.93 MB             
0d3e866c82f3        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    131.2 MB            
c28cbef85c39        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    44.67 MB            
3f0d3d140ce1        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B                 
17bd2058e0c6        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:76679eeb94129df23c   125.1 MB
```

That means, the untagged images cannot be removed, and I think by design the total size used should still be ~670MB since docker stores only the diffs for dependent images.

**Please let me know how to reduce the disk usage of devicemapper.**

Comment: Could you show me what prints when you run "docker images -a" ? Just to see if there are any old layers left.

Comment: Added the results for docker images -a, and I see a large number of seemingly unused images

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/chadoe/docker-cleanup-volumes?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a rather [old bug with devicemapper](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3182), especially if you are using ext3. If you are using ext3, then [upgrading to ext4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/UpgradeToExt4) may solve your issues. The main symptom of the bug is that devicemapper doesn't free up deleted images and volumes.

Short of that, you can completely purge /var/lib/docker and do a reinstall since you say you're ok with data loss.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the volumes associated with the container!

To achieve this, use this command:

```
docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
```